# How to manually adjust gamma, and rgb balance in Wayland

Tags: fedora, gnome, wayland, color-management

I see gnome settings allows me to load ICC color profiles per screen and has a button to calibrate (from what I've read, using a calibration tool).
In Windows, I was able to manually mess with the gamma and rgb balance in my graphics driver, seeing the results immediately. Is there a way to create an ICC profile by eye?

Comment: I've been sharing this github repo https://github.com/zb3/gnome-gamma-tool - no credit  to me, it's not my repo - which let me set gamma. It creates an icc profile which implements the gamma and is visually immediate (it even includes a brief timeout where it will go back to the previous active profile if you don't commit to the change). I haven't explored all it's options or tried to update it to be more interactive (say, display color bars in the terminal window and let you adjust gamma with keystrokes), but could be a good starting point for such a tool.